# Using AudioTrack in Android to play a WAV file

Tags: android, wav, audio-streaming

I'm working with Android, trying to make my AudioTrack application play a Windows .wav file (Tada.wav).  Frankly, it shouldn't be this hard, but I'm hearing a lot of strange stuff.  The file is saved on my phone's mini SD card and reading the contents doesn't seem to be a problem, but when I play the file (with parameters I'm only PRETTY SURE are right), I get a few seconds of white noise before the sound seems to resolve itself into something that just may be right.

I have successfully recorded and played my own voice back on the phone -- I created a .pcm file according to the directions in this example:

http://emeadev.blogspot.com/2009/09/raw-audio-manipulation-in-android.html

(without the backwards masking)...

Anybody got some suggestions or awareness of an example on the web for playing a .wav file on an Android??

Thanks,
R.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I stumbled on the answer (frankly, by trying &^@! I didn't think would work), in case anybody's interested...  In my original code (which is derived from the example in the link in the original post), the data is read from the file like so:

```
    InputStream             is  = new FileInputStream       (file);
    BufferedInputStream     bis = new BufferedInputStream   (is, 8000);
    DataInputStream         dis = new DataInputStream       (bis);      //  Create a DataInputStream to read the audio data from the saved file

    int i = 0;                                                          //  Read the file into the "music" array
    while (dis.available() > 0)
    {
        music[i] = dis.readShort();                                     //  This assignment does not reverse the order
        i++;
    }

    dis.close();                                                        //  Close the input stream
```

In this version, music[] is array of SHORTS.  So, the readShort() method would seem to make sense here, since the data is 16-bit PCM...  However, on the Android that seems to be the problem.  I changed that code to the following:

```
     music=new byte[(int) file.length()];//size & length of the file
    InputStream             is  = new FileInputStream       (file);
    BufferedInputStream     bis = new BufferedInputStream   (is, 8000);
    DataInputStream         dis = new DataInputStream       (bis);      //  Create a DataInputStream to read the audio data from the saved file

    int i = 0;                                                          //  Read the file into the "music" array
    while (dis.available() > 0)
    {
        music[i] = dis.readByte();                                      //  This assignment does not reverse the order
        i++;
    }

    dis.close();                                                        //  Close the input stream
```

In this version, music[] is an array of BYTES.  I'm still telling the AudioTrack that it's 16-bit PCM data, and my Android doesn't seem to have a problem with writing an array of bytes into an AudioTrack thus configured...  Anyway, it finally sounds right, so if anyone else wants to play Windows sounds on their Android, for some reason, that's the solution.  Ah, Endianness......

R.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it answers the question. ;)

Comment: I could've sworn I left a "Thank You, Gary" right here, but it's not here now...  Thank you, Gary!!

Comment: This [article](http://computermusicblog.com/blog/2008/08/29/reading-and-writing-wav-files-in-java) seems to be on the topic: differences between using Java's short and byte when it comes to reading WAV format.

Comment: How to know music[] length to inizialize ?

Comment: Basically, just "big enough."  If you know the file you'll be sending it, use a value just larger than its size, otherwise you more-or-less have to pull a number out of your butt.

Answer (score 12):

I found a lot of long answers to this question. My final solution, which given all the cutting and pasting is hardly mine, comes down to:

```
public boolean play() {

    int i = 0;
    byte[] music = null;
    InputStream is = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.noise);

    at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100,
        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
        minBufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

    try{
        music = new byte[512];
        at.play();

        while((i = is.read(music)) != -1)
            at.write(music, 0, i);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    at.stop();
    at.release();
    return STOPPED;
}
```

STOPPED is just a "true" sent back as a signal to reset the pause/play button.
And in the class initializer:

```
public Mp3Track(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100,
        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
}
```

Context is just "this" from the calling activity.
You can use a FileInputStream on the sdcard, etc. My files are in res/raw

Comment: Thanks for this, out of all the answers I tried this one gave the best result. Although I still get a little audio click when the track starts....

Comment: I'm getting a click noise at the beginning and end, also the playback surpasses the end of file, and continues playing audio that is not even in any audio file. Weird!

Comment: Audio plays in slow motion. What could be the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Are you skipping the first 44 bytes of the file before you dump the rest of the file's data into the buffer?  The first 44 bytes are the WAVE header and they would sound like random noise if you tried to play them.

Also, are you sure you are creating the AudioTrack with the same properties as the WAVE you are trying to play (sample rate, bit rate, number of channels, etc)?  Windows actually does a good job of giving this information to you in the File Properties page:
[image]

Comment: I have tried every combination of skipping the header and not that I can think of -- without much luck.  The white noise sound lasts MUCH longer than 44 bites worth.  Tada.wav is a 168 kByte file, so "playing" the header should barely be noticeable, right?

Comment: Correct, the file header would generate garbage for a very short time.  Are you sure you are creating the AudioTrack with the same properties as the WAVE you are trying to play (sample rate, bit rate, number of channels, etc)?

Comment: I have a hex editor and I sure think I'm getting the numbers out of the header properly.  I'm kind of surprised I haven't been able to find a wav file analyzer of some sort on the Internet.  I'm stumped, AND Windows Media player can certainly play the file...

Comment: Window's file Properties page actually does a good job of giving this information to you, if you want to sanity check your values.

Comment: Keep in mind that wav header is not always 44 bytes. For 32 bit float data header is 58 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

As said by [Aaron C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411500/aaron-c), you have to skip initial 44 bytes or (as I prefer) read first 44 bytes that are the WAVE header. In this way you know how many channels, bits per sample, length, etc... the WAVE contains.

[Here](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/speech/srec/WaveHeader.java.shtml) you can find a good implementation of a WAVE header parser/writer.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't perpetuate terrible parsing code. WAV parsing is trivial to implement
http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/
and you will thank yourself by being able to parse things such as the sampling rate, bit depth, and number of channels.

Also x86 and ARM (at least by default) are both little endian , so native-endian WAV files should be fine without any shuffling.

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if you specified what parsing code you think is terrible and why.

Answer (score 1):

Just confirm if you have `AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM` and not `AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC` in the `AudioTrack` constructor:

```
AudioTrack at = new AudioTrack(
  AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
  sampleRate,
  AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,
  AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
  // buffer length in bytes
  outputBufferSize,
  AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample wav file:
http://www.mauvecloud.net/sounds/pcm1644m.wav

Sample Code:

```
public class AudioTrackPlayer {
    Context mContext;
    int minBufferSize;
    AudioTrack at;
    boolean STOPPED;

    public AudioTrackPlayer(Context context) {
        Log.d("------","init");
        mContext = context;
        minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    }

    public boolean play() {
        Log.d("------","play");
        int i = 0;
        byte[] music = null;
        InputStream is = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.pcm1644m);

        at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                minBufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
        try {
            music = new byte[512];
            at.play();

            while ((i = is.read(music)) != -1)
                at.write(music, 0, i);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        at.stop();
        at.release();
        return STOPPED;
    }
}
```