# Playing audio sound using mediaplayer taking delay

Tags: android, android-listview, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I have a listview having audio voice in each row.I need to play the voice on click of seekbar & display progress in seekbar and pause the voice on click of seekbar again.Need to implement multiplay functionality also.
I tried using  media player,but it is taking some delay before playing the voice.It is because of MediaPlayer.prepare() call.How to overcome that 2-4 seconds delay..Please help me out.

Comment: have you tried using audiotrack() ??

Comment: Na I didn try..Could you pls suggest an example using audiotrack()

Comment: You have bug somewhere, prepare doesn't take 5 seconds, it's less than 1 second when playing local file.

Comment: paste ur code .... prepare never take long time for local file from file system...

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372813/android-audiotrack-playing-wav-file-getting-only-white-noise

Answer (score 0):

SoundPool is the best if not only way to do it, check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) out and [this tutorial](http://mycodeandlife.wordpress.com/2012/07/09/android-sound-pool/) Hope it helps.