# What paramaters does android's AudioTrack need to play the output of TextToSpeech.synthesizeToFile?

Tags: java, android, android-things, google-aiy

I want to play the output of android's [TextToSpeech.synthesizeToFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#synthesizeToFile(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.io.File,%20java.lang.String)) using [AudioTrack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack) but fear I'm passing AudioTrack's builders the wrong parameters. I copied one of the files generated with TextToSpeech.synthesizeToFile using adb and put in in [this github file](https://github.com/user-name-is-taken/androidthings-googleassistant/blob/master/step1-start-here/src/main/java/com/example/androidthings/assistant/tempSoundFile8290688667049742717.wav) if you want to see TextToSpeech.synthesizeToFile's output for yourself. When I run `play tempSoundFile8290688667049742717.wav` in linux, the file plays the text I wrote (*hello world*), and prints the following:

```
play WARN alsa: can't encode 0-bit Unknown or not applicable

tempSoundFile8290688667049742717.wav:

 File Size: 39.4k     Bit Rate: 353k
  Encoding: Signed PCM    
  Channels: 1 @ 16-bit   
Samplerate: 22050Hz      
Replaygain: off         
  Duration: 00:00:00.89  

In:100%  00:00:00.89 [00:00:00.00] Out:19.7k [!=====|=====!]        Clip:0    
Done.
```

accordingly, I'm setting AudioTrack's parameters as follows:

```java
private AudioDeviceInfo findAudioDevice(int deviceFlag, int deviceType) {
    AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) this.context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    AudioDeviceInfo[] adis = manager.getDevices(deviceFlag);
    for (AudioDeviceInfo adi : adis) {
        if (adi.getType() == deviceType) {
            return adi;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

AudioDeviceInfo mAudioOutputDevice = findAudioDevice(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS,
        AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUS);

AudioAttributes.Builder audioAttributesBuilder = new AudioAttributes.Builder().
        setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION_SIGNALLING).
        setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH).
        setFlags(AudioAttributes.FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED);
attributes = audioAttributesBuilder.build();

int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(22050, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

AudioTrack.Builder atBuilder = new AudioTrack.Builder();
//builder.setAudioAttributes()
AudioFormat.Builder afBuilder = new AudioFormat.Builder();

afBuilder.setEncoding(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
        .setChannelMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO)
        .setSampleRate(22050);

atBuilder.setAudioFormat(afBuilder.build())
        .setTransferMode(AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM)
        .setBufferSizeInBytes(minBufferSize)
        .setAudioAttributes(attributes);


at = atBuilder.build();
at.setPreferredDevice(mAudioOutputDevice);

File myFile = File.createTempFile("tempSoundFile", ".wav");
            myFile.deleteOnExit();
            myFile.setWritable(true);
            myFile.setReadable(true);
```

and later plays the file, using code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372813/android-audiotrack-playing-wav-file-getting-only-white-noise):

```java
/**
* Code taken from here:
* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372813/android-audiotrack-playing-wav-file-getting-only-white-noise
*/
private void playWav(){
    Log.d(TAG, "Playing speech to text wav file");
    String filepath = this.myFile.getAbsolutePath();

    int i = 0;
    int BUFFER_SIZE = 512;
    byte[] s = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "file path is: " + filepath);
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(filepath);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fin);


        at.play();

        while((i = dis.read(s, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) > -1){
            at.write(s, 0, i);
            Log.v(TAG, Arrays.toString(s));

        }
        at.stop();
        at.release();
        dis.close();
        fin.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Of course, calls to these are spread across different async calls as you can see [in my code](https://github.com/user-name-is-taken/androidthings-googleassistant/tree/master/step1-start-here/src/main/java/com/example/androidthings/assistant), but I've debugged all that with log statements and the debugger and don't see any issues. playWav() is getting hit when I expect, but not playing anything.

### edit:

My primary motivation for using AudioTrack is to make it TextToSpeech compatible with the [raspberry pi voice kit](https://aiyprojects.withgoogle.com/voice/)'s [android things library](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-googleassistant). Using AudioTrack will allow me to play textToSpeech over I2S (or any speaker I choose).

### edit 2, a deeper look:

According to [this website](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/), wav files have a 44 byte header that tells what all these parameters are. In this header, at:

- position 20, 2 bytes that dictate the file type (little endian) (16 for PCM)
- position 22, 2 bytes that dictate the number of channels (1 for Mono, 2 for Stereo) (little endian)
- position 24, 4 bytes that dictate the sample rate (little endian)
- and finally at position 34, 2 bytes dictate the bits per sample (little endian)

here is a hex dump of the above mentioned file:

```
$ hd -n 44 tempSoundFile8290688667049742717.wav 
00000000  52 49 46 46 f8 99 00 00  57 41 56 45 66 6d 74 20  |RIFF....WAVEfmt |
00000010  10 00 00 00 01 00 01 00  22 56 00 00 44 ac 00 00  |........"V..D...|
00000020  02 00 10 00 64 61 74 61  d4 99 00 00              |....data....|
0000002c
```

Comment: Looks like you're kinda blowing past the WAV header, but that doesn't explain the silence. I assume [`SoundPool`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool) or `MediaPlayer` won't work for your use case? Might want to test out your hardware setup by just writing out (repeatedly/infinitely) a square wave, instead of the results of `dis.read()`, e.g. `short[] wavecycle={-0x7FFF, -0x7FFF, -0x7FFF, -0x7FFF, 0x7FFF, 0x7FFF, 0x7FFF, 0x7FFF}`. Also it's likely `stop()` is being called before the sound is finished playing, b/c it's called as soon as the last write completes.

Comment: I need the __setPreferredDevice__ capability. MediaPlayer [has it in API level 28](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setPreferredDevice(android.media.AudioDeviceInfo)), but android things is level 27. I didn't see it in SoundPool. I know the hardware works, because the assistant portion of my code works (if you look at the link to my github).

Comment: My point about the WAV header is that you're not supposed to send that to `AudioTrack`, (as mentioned in the question you linked). `AudioTrack.write()` does not interpret header information; it regards everything you give it as PCM data. This will cause a very brief burst of noise at the beginning of playback. But that's just an aside, let me look at your github for a minute...

Comment: What happens if you try it without the `setAudioAttributes(attributes)` call? What you want to do is set it up as closely as possible to the `AudioTrack` you have that is working -- just a different sample rate. I'm not sure, but I think either `USAGE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION_SIGNALLING` or `CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH` is causing a different device to be used. Besides, you don't need them anyway; a sound is a sound, whether it's voice or music. An `AudioTrack` doesn't interpret PCM data differently based on whether you configured it for voice or not.

Comment: I tried it without setting attributes, it's still not working. I added the `mDac.setSdMode(Max98357A.SD_MODE_LEFT);` before calling playWav() and `mDac.setMode(Max98357A.SD_MODE_SHUTDOWN);` after. This made the microphone click which is what the working code does, but it doesn't play the wav file. I also tried hooking up an osiliscope to the mic leads, which shows no signal other than the click. When I Log the data sent to .write, I can see it, but it don't think it's making it to the mic. I also tried adding a sleep after the write to no effect.

Comment: Just tried this code myself on the emulator, and I can verify it works. With or without the `attributes`. Of course, I'm not using your specialized audio hardware.

Comment: I think the thing you need to focus on is that you already have a 16-bit mono `AudioTrack` that works. So, arguably, if you just found a way to get your WAV data into _that_ `AudioTrack`, it would be certain to play (albeit at the wrong sample rate).

Comment: You should probably check the return value from `write()` just to be safe.

Comment: One other thing -- and I'm just spitballing, here -- but I'm not confident that Max98357A chip can handle two different sample rates at the same time. You're not  properly cleaning up your 16KHz `AudioTrack`, and if you try to make a 22.5KHz one at the same time, it could get confused. As a matter of fact, looking at this [datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX98357A-MAX98357B.pdf), it only supports 8/16/48/96 KHz!

Comment: I'm going to try switching to [a cloud TTS engine](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) that can set the sample rate. If that works, I'll lett you know and accept your answer if you post it.

Comment: Sure. Consider just changing the 22050 to 16000. It'll make your female voice sound like a dude, but otherwise it should still work.

Comment: something like [this](https://github.com/ashqal/android-libresample)?

Comment: Well, yes, that looks like it would correct the pitch... but I'm not sure you completely understood my last comment - I meant, literally just change the numbers in your source code, from 22050 to 16000 (2 places).

Comment: Ok, so I can play audio sampled at 22050 at 16000 and it will simply change the tone?

Comment: That's exactly it.

Comment: I figured out the problem, switching to `at.write(s, 0,  BUFFER_SIZE, AudioTrack.WRITE_BLOCKING);` fixed it.

Comment: Hmm. Strange, but if it works, it works!