# convert WAVE file into vectors in Android

Tags: android, matlab, audio, signal-processing, wave

Im searching for a way to convert Wave files into a list of numbers to cross-correlate the resulting vectors (like the numbers you get when you read a wave file on MATLAB)

`0.6653
   -0.8445
    0.9589
   -0.9999
    0.9643
   -0.8547
    0.6797
   -0.4525
    0.1907
    0.0858
   -0.3557
    0.5983
   -0.7951
    0.9309
   -0.9953
    0.9835
   -0.8962
    0.7402
   -0.5275
    0.2742`

is there a way to do that in Android or even C/C++? i really dont know how to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WAVE file format is fairly simple, especially if you're interested in linear PCM encoded data. Descriptions of the format is available from various sources, such as [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) and [here](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html).

Using these, you should be able to decode:

- the header ("RIFF" chunk)
- the "fmt " chunk which contains various information such as the number of bytes per samples, the number of channels (ie. mono, stereo, or more), sampling rate, etc.
- and the "data" chunk which if the main thing that you'll want to look at in order to create a MATLAB-like vector.

If you're dealing with single channel (ie. mono) WAVE files, the data is fairly straightforward to decode. The number of samples should then corresponds (give-or-take a few bytes for padding) to the size of the data block divided by the number of bytes per sample (the number of bits per sample is available from the "fmt " chunk). The mapping of the samples' integer to a [0-1] floating point value can be done by multiplying by a constant (eg. 1.0/128 for 1-byte-per-sample).

For multi-channel WAVE files, keep in mind that channel data are interleaved (e.g. sample 1 left/right, sample 2 left/right, ...)

Note also that there are a number of tutorial/samples floating around (such as [this sample in C](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/loading-a-wave-file-r709) or [this sample in Java](https://code.google.com/p/music-synthesizer-for-android/source/browse/core/src/com/google/synthesizer/core/wave/WaveReader.java?r=72190eccf28b85c44ae3435034a6a06da9e9a3e6)), and various open source sound libraries which  you may use as a starting point.

Comment: Thank you. do you have any idea that if smartphones ADC's can decode a wave file if i send it over sound?

Comment: Not an expert on Android API, but check SoundPool & MediaPlayer for high level API, AudioTrack (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372813/android-audiotrack-playing-wav-file-getting-only-white-noise and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925030/using-audiotrack-in-android-to-play-a-wav-file) for a sample buffer level API, or the OpenSL & NDK (see http://audioprograming.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/android-audio-streaming-with-opensl-es-and-the-ndk/) for an even lower level native API. But sending _raw_ wave file directly over to the ADC is unlikely to work (as explained in some links).