# White noise while playing audio in c#

Tags: c#, audio, xamarin.forms

I have a audio player, made from AudioTrack, that gets and write byte[] packs of audio data (not the entire this at a time, but smaller pieces). The data is constantly playing, but sometimes - random, I get whie noise over that audio, and if I wait a little it will then play normal. This happens randomly. Is it because the buffer may be to small? I am playing wav files. This is my code:

```
public void Read()
{
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
    {                
        int _bufferSize;
        AudioTrack _output;

        _bufferSize = AudioTrack.GetMinBufferSize(44100, ChannelOut.Stereo, Android.Media.Encoding.Pcm16bit);

        _output = new AudioTrack(Android.Media.Stream.Music, 44100, ChannelOut.Stereo, Android.Media.Encoding.Pcm16bit, _bufferSize, AudioTrackMode.Stream);
        _output.Play();

        while (mmInStream.CanRead)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[10000];
                mmInStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
                _output.Write(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
            {
                _output.Stop();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Input stream was disconnected", ex);
            }
        }
        _output.Stop();
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [AudioTrack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack) article, we can see that it said that **It allows streaming of PCM audio buffers to the audio sink for playback**, wav is not PCm audio, so it will cause some white noise.

I find one article about using AudioTrack to play wav file that you can take a look:

[Using AudioTrack in Android to play a WAV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925030/using-audiotrack-in-android-to-play-a-wav-file)